# How to use role based authentication on client side reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created 2 components one is login form and other component displays table with some random data generated through faker.js After user login, table component with some data is displayed. That component also has 2 buttons on top right corner so I want to show those buttons only if `user === ADMIN` if `user === USER` then I don't want to show those 2 buttons. How can I do this ? Should I create a separate component excluding those 2 buttons ?

Login.js:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { Button, Form, Header } from "semantic-ui-react";
import './loginForm.css';

class LoginForm extends Component {

    state = {}

    handleChange = (e, { name, value }) => this.setState({ [name]: value })

    handleSubmit = () => {
      this.setState({ urnNumber: '', password: '' })  
      this.props.history.push('/user')
    }

    render() {
        const { urnNumber, password } = this.state 

        return(
          <Form className="formStyle" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <Header className="title" as='h1'>Account Portal Login</Header>
            <Header className="info" as='h5'>Please login with your URN number. If you have not been assigned a
            password, you can create one below and login afterwards</Header>
            <Header className="info" as='h4'>Please login below</Header>
            <Form.Field>
              <Form.Input label="URN number" value={urnNumber} placeholder="Enter URN number" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </Form.Field>
            <Form.Field>
              <Form.Input label="Password" value={password} placeholder="Enter password" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            </Form.Field>
            <Button className="loginButton">Login</Button>
          </Form>
        )
    }
};

export default LoginForm;
```

TableComponent.js:

```
const RemittancePage = () => (
    <Grid className={styles.container}>
        <Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Column width={11}>
                <Header as='h2' className={styles.title}>Remittance Page</Header>
            </Grid.Column>
            <Grid.Column floated='right' width={5}>
                <Button primary className={styles.formButton}>Remittance</Button>
                <Button primary className={styles.reportButton}>Generate Report + </Button>
            </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Column width={16}>
                <Table celled selectable className={styles.remittanceForm}>
                    <Table.Header>
                        <Table.Row>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>ID</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Name</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>URN number</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Parishes</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Remittance</Table.HeaderCell>
                        </Table.Row>
                    </Table.Header>

                    <Table.Body>
                        <Table.Row>
                            <Table.Cell>{faker.random.number()}</Table.Cell>
                            <Table.Cell>{faker.name.findName()}</Table.Cell>
                            <Table.Cell>{faker.random.number()}</Table.Cell>
                            <Table.Cell>{faker.address.streetAddress()}</Table.Cell>
                            <Table.Cell>{faker.date.weekday()}</Table.Cell>
                        </Table.Row>
                        // Some more rows 

                    </Table.Body>
                </Table>
            </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
    </Grid>
)

export default RemittancePage;
```

App.js:

```
  var user1 = {
  "number": "123",
  "role": "ADMIN"
};

var user2 = {
  "number": "456",
  "role": "USER"
};

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
          <Switch>
              <div>
                <Route exact path="/" component={LoginForm}/>
                {/* <Route path="/user" component={RemittancePage} /> */}
                <Route path="/user" render={(user1) => <RemittancePage {...user1} />} 
                />
                <Route path="/remittanceform" component={RemittanceForm} />
              </div>
          </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Screenshot:
In below screenshot 2 buttons in top right should be displayed only if `user == ADMIN` if `user === USER` then I don't want to display it. How can I do this ?
[image]

Comment: Is `user` something you have in state? Is it `urnNumber` or something else?

Comment: @RyanC I am not using backend or database I have hardcoded 2 users one is admin and other is user

Comment: Hardcoded where? Where is user defined/set?

Comment: @RyanC See updated app.js

Comment: I still don't see how you're getting the user. In `<Route path="/user" render={(user1) => <RemittancePage {...user1} />} />`, user1 is going to be the route props (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props) not your `user1` variable declared at the top of App.js (see this code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nnzwz247rj as demonstration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the following structure inside of your RemittancePage jsx template:

```html
this.props.user.permissions === 'ADMIN' ? <Grid.Column floated='right' width={5}>
                <Button primary className={styles.formButton}>Remittance</Button>
                <Button primary className={styles.reportButton}>Generate Report + </Button>
</Grid.Column> : null
```

Assuming you have `user` passed to props.

Basically, same as in plain JS. Just an inline conditional.